# VB.NET reference sender form in a separate module

Tags: vb.net, loops, userform, sender

I am trying to loop through each panel and control in each user form I have in my application so I wrote a subroutine to call upon initialization of each user form. The problem I have encountered is referencing the sender user form in a separate module. The code I have:

```
    Sub Configure_UI()

        For Each Control_Panel As Panel In sender.Controls.OfType(Of Panel) 'Loop through panels
            For Each control In Control_Panel.Controls
                Configure_Control(control)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

The error that it gives says "Sender is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.". SO I wonder how do I fix this. What I need is a dynamic solution where sender is the form.name.

Could someone, please, help me out please?

Comment: Just use form (not form name!) as parameter for you sub.

Comment: I mean how do I do that? Because "Sub Configure_UI(sender)" doesn't fix the issue except that the error disappears. Itš a sub to be used with any user form, so it needs to reference the sender user form from which the sub was called

Comment: Doing ``Sub Configure_UI(ByVal sender As Form)`` seems to move the issue forward but now I can't call it because it says "Argument not specified for parameter 'sender' of 'Public Sub Configure_UI(sender As Form)'"

Answer (score 0):

so the solution is as follows

```
    Sub Configure_UI(ByVal sender As Form)

        For Each Control_Panel As Panel In sender.Controls.OfType(Of Panel) 'Loop through panels
            For Each control In Control_Panel.Controls
                Configure_Control(control)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

and the call to it from user form initialization is:

```
Configure_UI(me)
```

Any suggestions on optimizing the solution?